# VBA Merging two codes

Tags: excel, vba

I've got two codes:

**1)** Takes each value from column and produces *.txt file with values name https://superuser.com/questions/387192/excel-create-text-file-named-after-a-cell-containing-other-cell-data

```
Sub CreateTxt()
'
For Each ce In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Row)
    Open ce & ".txt" For Output As #1
    Write #1, ce.Offset(0, 1) & " " & ce.Offset(0, 2)
Close #1
Next ce
End Sub
```

**2)** Finds last, non empty row

```
Sub LastRowInOneColumn()

Dim LastRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
MsgBox LastRow
End Sub
```

My question -- how do I implement *LastRow* from **2)** code into **1)** code? Thanks for help!

Comment: How about **calling** `LastRowOneColumn()` from `CreateText()` and keeping them separate?

Comment: implement what? it's really unclear what you're trying to do

Comment: What is your actual requirement?  Do you want to create a file for the last row only?

Comment: **1)** code crashes excel, because it takes whole A column, not the last non empty cell ( End(xlDown).Row doesn't do the trick). That's why I want to use **2)** code, which finds last row's number, with non empty cell (instead of Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Row)). How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Call` procedure: place `Call LastRowOneColumn` in your code, and it will jump to that procedure when that line of code is reached.

An alternative would be to copy and paste the code from LastRowOneColumn() into CreateTxt().

Comment: I did try to copy and paste the **2)** code to **1)**, but it didn't work -- the code does nothing. Here is what it looks like:
http://pastebin.com/PausF7af

Comment: Instead of `LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` you need `LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`. Give that a try.